# ArcGIS android mapview: Invalid coordinates for the visible area when zooming out too much

Tags: android, arcgis-runtime

We are using ArcGIS Runtime SDK v. 100.11.0 for Android and need to identify the objects (Their coordinates are known to us as Latitude + Longitude) that are currently visible to the user on screen.

We've tried to use the [MapView.getVisibleArea](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/MapView.html#getVisibleArea()) and [MapView.screenToLocation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/MapView.html#screenToLocation(android.graphics.Point)) methods to identity the currently visible area (so later we can use it to identify the visible custom objects).

In both cases we encounter the same issue: the methods start providing coordinates' WGS84 representation with NaN values whenever you zoom out the map view so that you see on screen more than the whole world (in other words: as soon as you can see some whitespace around the map).

Is there any way to identify the visible area defined in the WGS84 coordinates?

*The issue can be reproduced also using SDK v. 100.15.0

Comment: Hi @Michael Krutoyarskiy: Did you find solution for this ?

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn no, the issue is still there. We limited how much a user can zoom out to avoid this issue in most cases.